# Crystal Reports HTML size

Tags: html, css, fonts, crystal-reports

I am using a Crystal report document which pulls in multiple data sets, one of which contains HTML tags. The rest of my document is size 8 Arial font, but as can be seen here the HTML is forcing the font to appear as size 12 if I choose the HTML Text interpretation. Is there any way to force any incoming text from the field in question to adhere to a specific size regardless of what the HTML text might say?

```
<FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; 
FONT-FAMILY:Calibri,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; 
BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ; 
COLOR: black; 
BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; 
BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ";>
Cargar contenedor no._________________ sello no. _______________<BR>Tomar medida desde el brace hasta la puerta del contenedor _________<BR>
</FONT>
```

Comment: You are already forcing to size 12 then what is the purpose of again setting the font size to 8?

Comment: The field is coming into our database from a Web app which is what adds the formatting into the data. For the Web App size 12 is what is required, however once it gets into our system, and forwarded to this report size 12 is larger than we would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution below:

Since you need entire field to get the font size as `8`. Take th filed in a formula and then `right click --> Format Field --> Font --> x-2` write below formula:

```
if Length(databasefield)> 0
then 8
```

To convert total field we are taking the length as `>0`. This will convert the font to size 8 in crystal reports

check the link:
http://www.maximumimpactsolutions.co.uk/blog/comments.asp?bd=139